# How to show the all items in recyclerview when you lock and unlock your phone?

Tags: android, kotlin

Adapter is working fine when first time landed on that fragment.But the items of adapter not showing when I lock my phone and unlock it. When I printed the size and arraylist all data got printed but there is no items showing on the screen.

I tried to call notifyDatasetChanged but nothing happend. I want to know the reason that why data is not showing when I lock and unlock the phone after data showing successfully on the screen.

Code of binding in adapter -->

```
if (mDocUploadedImagesPathArrayList.size > 0){
    binding.uploadedDocumentLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    documentListAdapter = DoctorDocumentImageAdapter(  
                          requireActivity(),
                          mDocUploadedImagesPathArrayList,
                          this
                          )
} else{
     binding.uploadedDocumentLayout.visibility = View.GONE
}
val mlayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(), 3)
binding.uploadedDocumentRecyclerview.layoutManager = mlayoutManager       
binding.uploadedDocumentRecyclerview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
binding.uploadedDocumentRecyclerview.adapter = documentListAdapter
```

where mDocUploadedImagesPathArrayList is the list I am getting from the API

While changing GridLayoutManager in LinearLayoutManager this problem got solved and also this is only happens on Realme C3 model not on other mobiles.
Any idea why this is happening on Realme C3 and with GridLayoutManager not with LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: can you provide your recyclerview adapter code and your fragment code?

Comment: You can get your ArrayList in the `onResume` method

Comment: I have tried to update the list in onResume but it's not working, items get disappeared when I unlock API.

Comment: remove the `if` condition and check,, if it works or not. Make it `Visible` from xml too if not

Comment: While changing GridLayoutManager in LinearLayoutManager this problem got solved and also this is only happens on Realme C3 model not on other mobiles.